# Exaggeration of “Capable”

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a word which means *capable, confident, legitimate.*

It should imply no negative connotation when used in this sentence:

> He wanted to become a (more) ____ accountant.

“Legitimate” would not work, because it implies that he was not legitimate before.

It needs to imply that he was a working accountant before, but became more capable. A phrase may also work, but the primary focus is to find a single word that describes this.

Comment: Have you consulted a dictionary/thesaurus? Are "accomplished", "skilled", "competent" inadequate?

Comment: "Skilled" should be considered, thought some might find it mildly strange when applied to "accountant" (rather than, say "mechanic" or "computer programmer").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/competent

*Competent*, most likely.

> - having the necessary ability, knowledge, or skill to do something successfully

Comment: "Competent" is often used with an implied negative connotation, to indicate the individual "meets requirements" but nothing more.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest the word *Proficient* as it implies a higher level of skill. Someone can be capable or legitimate without being proficient.

Comment: Related is "credible", which implies that he has reached a level of skill and legitimacy such that peers or clients now believe him competent.

Comment: @Brian “He’s a credible accountant” to me sounds like he’s an actor whose impression of an accountant is so good that he could be believed to actually be one.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet: touché. But if all the world's a stage... and he's good enough to fool his peers, what's the difference?  that is, until he comes up against the CPA exam!  (There's a reason I put that in a comment; I had a feeling it wasn't really a "credible" answer.)

Answer (score 0):

"**Professional**" would tap into concepts of both capability and legitimacy, since it implies both competence and some form of collective regulatory control.

Comment: “Became a more professional accountant” could imply that he did not meet basic standards of professionalism before, and “became a professional accountant” implies that he was not employed as an accountant before.